# How can I use multiple debounceTime on one Observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have an input html element and doing a basic type ahead search function using Observables:

The code:

```
   @Output() keywordChange = new EventEmitter();

   this.keyword$ = Observable.fromEvent(myInput, 'keyup');
    this.keyword$
      .map((event: any) => event.target.value)
      .debounceTime(200)
      .subscribe(keyword => this.keywordChange.emit(keyword));
```

So basically I'm capturing any keywords typed with at at least 200 ms between each keyup.

Now I want to save whatever the user is searching for in a cookie, in order to show them "Your latest searches" but I want to wait 3000 ms before saving 
the values typed.

I know the following code won't work but just to illustrate, I want to achieve something similiar to this:

```
    this.keyword$
      .map((event: any) => event.target.value)
      .debounceTime(200)
      .subscribe(keyword => this.keywordChange.emit(keyword))
      .debounceTime(3000)
      .subscribe(keyword => addKeyWordToLatestSearches(keyword));
```

Is this possible somehow, chaining operators to do multiple things with different debounceTimes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you probably want to `share` the initial subscription to have the possibility of processing the emitted data in two independent ways? As you don't want to subscribe twice on the original source, you could use the [`share` operator](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/share.md) of RxJS.

```
const keyupValue$ = this.keyword$
  .map((event: any) => event.target.value)
  .share();

keyupValue$
  .debounceTime(200)
  .subscribe(keyword => this.keywordChange.emit(keyword))

keyupValue$ 
  .debounceTime(3000)
  .subscribe(keyword => addKeyWordToLatestSearches(keyword));
```

Comment: What is the consequence of not using share in this example? I tried it out and it seems your example works even without share(). Does share simply make it so that I only have to keep track of one subscription instead of multiple?

Comment: `share()` makes your stream multicast thus both subscriptions are to the same source. Your example will work without `share()` because of its simplicity. When you start having resource heavy subscriptions (db calls, http calls, etc) `share()` is the way to go

Comment: This really depends on your source observable. But for example when using the angular 2 http API and doing this stuff without sharing, every subscriber would trigger an own http request. So the `share` method creates a subject that you can think of as a combination of subscriber and observable which handles more than one subscriber by reusing the original stream's events.